# Custom Serialization to allow Maps in the ngrx store?

Tags: ngrx-store

We are receiving a substantial blob of data from a server and storing it the store in ngrx. Some of it should be organized as a map from keys to values. So, we wrote:

```
Immutable.Map<string, string>()
```

as the data type. (There are other places where the types would be `<string, some_serializable_class>` We enabled all of the runtime checks, and ngrx reminded us that these maps are not serializable. It would not take very much code to safely serialize and deserialize them, of course.

Is there a place in the ngrx architecture to put our own serialization? If we do so, will the runtime check be aware?

Answer (score 0):

@ngrx/entity turns out to be the intended solution to this problem?